# Is Ayurveda treatment effective for modern diseases?

Tags: treatment, alternative-medicine

[Ayurveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayurveda) is an ancient treatment from India which is 3000 years old, based on experience and observation.

Is Ayurveda good against modern diseases like tuberculosis, cancer etc?

Comment: I can't add tags like Ayurveda, alternate medicine. If you can please add. Thank you.

Comment: Like any other medicine, the effectiveness of any treatment will need to be studied per illness.  You list two here.  Even in those two, studies on cancer treatment will look a specific type of cancer (breast, lung, colon, etc).  I do not think many things have been studied at all if there isn't a drug they are looking to use.  There are studies where Ayurveda is lumped in with all alternative therapies, but that isn't very helpful.